# How do I close only one Google Chrome window in macOS using mouse?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Ex: I have 3 Chrome windows (each has multiple open tabs). Pressing on the red button in the upper left corner

[image]

closes my whole session and I don't want other instances to also die. Only one of them with 4 tabs.
<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> works only for the current tab, not the current window.

How do I achieve this with using mouse? How do I achieve it with the keyboard? (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> closes all Chrome windows so, also, not good).

I am running Google Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) on macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

Comment: What is the version of macOS and Google Chrome that you are running?

Comment: macOS Mojave 10.14.5
| Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) - latest, I believe.

Answer (score 10):

File → Close Window (⇧⌘W).

⌘W closes the tab which will close the window if this is the last tab, but ⇧⌘W closes the window containing any number of tabs.

This menu and shortcut is standard macOS working in all tabbed apps implementing macOS tabs, and Google Chrome has applied this shortcut to their tab implementation.

Answer (score 1):

To close the current window, press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

Another way to do so is to click on File > Close Window.

Refer to the attached screenshot: 
[image]